# ng-disabled within angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have an angular directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("myButtons", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            bdisabled: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "buttons.html"
    }
});
```

template:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="{{bdisabled}}" />
```

html:

```
<my-buttons bdisabled="!form.$valid"></my-buttons>
```

I'm trying to set the disabled state of the button in my template. The above code almost works.

The form loads and is valid, the html is rendered as follows:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="bdisabled()" value="Save" ng-disabled="false" disabled="disabled">
```

When I make the form invalid ng-disabled changes to true but disabled="disabled" stays no matter what.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `ng-disabled` is angular directive no need to use the curly brackets

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="bdisabled" />
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I knew it would be a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

Change `ng-disabled="{{bdisabled}}"` to `ng-disabled="bdisabled"`,

No need of interpolation operators, as its already in angular scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the variable itself inside the ng-disabled like`ng-disabled='disabled'`
No need of interpolation operator since it is a native angular directive